# How to "take real-time screenshots" of live streaming rooms

Tags: node.js, reactjs, opentok, tokbox

I am using OpenTok's SDKs and APIs to build a live streaming and video conferencing website. I am wondering how websites like Twitch take a "real-time screenshot" of each streaming room and display it on their websites so that users can have a glance at the content of a room. Besides, is it possible to achieve this feature using Zoom's APIs? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Manik here from OpenTok.

You can use the `getImgData` methods from the OpenTok SDK to capture screenshot of publishers and subscribers:

- [Publisher.getImgData](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getImgData)
- [Subscriber.getImgData](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getImgData)

These methods do not take screenshots of the application, but they give you base64 encoded strings of the live video which you can then use to reconstruct the view.

Hope this helps!